# Bind checkbox to boolean variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, checkbox, boolean

I have quite a lot of checkboxes on my page and each checkbox corresponds with a certain variable in my JavaScript code. Currently, I have this kind of code for each checkbox:

```
$("#checkbox_var1").click(function() {
    Settings.var1 = $(this).checked();
});
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to store a reference to a variable in an element (using `data()` perhaps) so that that's sufficient to bind a checkbox to a boolean variable. My current code becomes rather long since I have a fair amount of checkboxes.

So is it possible to bind a checkbox to a boolean variable directly? Or is there a general way of binding an element's value to a variable?

Comment: You might want to check out knockoutjs (http://knockoutjs.com/). It will probably satisfy your needs to bind an object to the state of a DOM element. However, it might be overkill for your situation.

Comment: That seems very interesting indeed, however it looks like it will actually become more complex in my situation. A complete extra library is not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same event handler for multiple check boxes, using the element's id to connect the two on the settings object, like so:

```
function checkListener (evt) {
    var id = this.id.substr(9);
    Settings[id] = $("#" + this.id + ":checked").length > 0;
}
```

Assuming you follow the same convention to name all pertinent check boxes in your application, you should adjust the substring function accordingly. Then, to apply to multiple check boxes simultaneously, you could do something along these lines:

```
$(":checkbox[id*='checkbox']").click(checkListener);
```

Which translates to: "For all input elements of type checkbox, that have an id containing 'checkbox'". This way, you can handle multiple checkboxes with a few lines of code.

Comment: That is an ingenious way, thank you very much. I forgot you can indeed access an object's properties by using `[]` as well, so that you can set a property which name is defined by a variable.